# Circle Geometry - Proving an equation

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying to solve this problem:

$\overline{AB}$ is the diameter of a circle with center $O$. $C$ is a point on the circle's circumference such that $\angle{COB}=\theta$. The area of the minor segment cut off by $AC$ is equal to twice the area of sector $BOC$. Prove that $3\theta = \pi - \sin(\theta)$.

This is what I did so far:

Area of sector $BOC$ = $2$(Area of sector $AOC$ - Area of minor segment $AC$)
$0.5r^2\theta$ = $2(0.5r^2(\pi - \theta) - (0.5r^2sin(\pi - \theta))$
                  ...
$3\theta = 2(\pi - sin (\pi - \theta))$

However, I couldn't simplify it more to get my answer right. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked nine questions here. It's time to learn mathjax. That helps us help you. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thanks. I've edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area of minor sector $BOC = \frac 12 r^2 \theta$

Area of minor segment cut off by chord $AC= \frac 12r^2 (\pi - \theta)  - \frac 12 r^2\sin (\pi - \theta)) = \frac 12r^2 ((\pi - \theta)  - \sin \theta))$ (using $\sin(\pi- \alpha) = \sin \alpha$ for any angle $\alpha$).

You're given that $\frac 12r^2 (\pi - \theta  - \sin \theta) = (2)(\frac 12 r^2 \theta)$

Hence $(\pi - \theta  - \sin \theta) = 2\theta$

Therefore $3\theta = \pi - \sin\theta$, as required.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that $\sin(\pi- \alpha) = \sin \alpha$. Thanks!